# Logstash: Handshake failed i/o timeout

Tags: logs

I have a problem between logstash-forward and logstash, i have installed correctly the SSL certificate but i have this error:

```
Failed to tls handshake with 111.111.111.111 read tcp 111.111.111.111:5000: i/o timeout
```

If i check SSL with openssl command work perfectly:

```
# openssl s_client -connect 111.111.111.111:5000

CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 C = XX, L = Default City, O = Default Company Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = XX, L = Default City, O = Default Company Ltd
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=XX/L=Default City/O=Default Company Ltd
   i:/C=XX/L=Default City/O=Default Company Ltd
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
.......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=XX/L=Default City/O=Default Company Ltd
issuer=/C=XX/L=Default City/O=Default Company Ltd
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: DH, 768 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1677 bytes and written 413 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 5512D461475996E5795A8F65F7C73A7047D6A99D9BBF30871FD91EA80BF110FE
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: C2FDF6944017E05247F103B106BA7313917C5B9BC516BFA05F875D4D8C0D294E797015FFA3E7BA5F744EF2D1E8925FB2
    Key-Arg   : None
    Krb5 Principal: None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    Start Time: 1427297377
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
closed
```

Comment: Are you in Japan with ISP au one net?